# Does Life Steal apply to damage dealt by Thorns?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some pieces of equipment have an attribute that states, "Melee attackers take X damage per hit."  Another attribute is, "X% of Damage Dealt Is Converted to Life."

My question is: Does damage dealt by Thorns count as "Damage Dealt" when calculating Life Steal?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I have quite a bit of thorn damage gear on and the 'show amount healed' option turned on, and I don't see any green numbers pop up when I get hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Life Steal does not apply to damage dealt by thorns.

Just tested this out, Stacking thorns with + life on hit, as well as damage converted to life.

I went to A3 hell in the depths (Before ghom) with Healing numbers turned on and just let monsters hit me. (had a shield on with 1550 Damage to attackers)

The life on hit and the damage conversion did not show up as healing numbers, and did not heal me.

When I attacked mobs it was clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

No. Life steal does not apply to damage dealt from thorns.

Comment: Do you have any reference supporting this? Just giving a fact is not a very good way to give a definite answer

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is true and no better answer was given.  Still, it would have been nice to have had some evidence (although James Jiao offered some evidence in a comment on the question).