# Does Life on Hit apply to damage dealt by Thorns?

Tags: diablo-iii

There is a question about [whether Life Steal applies to damage dealt by Thorns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70105/26866).

I'm asking about whether Life on Hit applies to damage dealt by Thorns.

These two are different:

Life Steal is "X% of Damage Dealt is Converted to Life."

Life on Hit is "Each Hit Adds X Life".

This question [How does life on hit work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/how-does-life-on-hit-work) does not say anything about Thorns. So, here is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not, my life on hit on my Barbarian is 1200+ and with monsters hitting me I do not gain any health from their attacks. Also I do have thorns damage, it is currently around 265 damage, so I am doing some thorns damage that would activate it if that was the case.